# ftp to azure storage blob (triggered processing)

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I want to transfert encrypted files from an `ftp server` to `azure blob storage container

Here is the workfow in question:

> `CSV` encrypted files on Ftp server ---------->`Trigger`(example: **On adding files**)----------> call to
>   some local programs or api that process decryption
>   and then create the output `csv` file in the blob container

the files are structured like following:

```
   Input CSV file:
        column1;column2;column3;
        encryptedvalue1;encryptedvalue2;encryptedvalue3;
```

and

```
Output csv file:
    column1;column2;column3;
    value1;value2;value3;
```

There is no file content transformation here but there is one more thing that i don't know if its doable or not:

I want to add the new blob under a specific folder depending of column1 value for example. (e.g. manage hierarchy of blob container from code)

I tried to create a `Logic App` and created the `ftp trigger` as first step, but i couldn't figure out what fits best as second step in my case.

I saw many suggestiong like using web jobs, others for azure functions and azure app service...

And because am kind of new to these structures of azure i came here to ask about the best way to do so and why ?

Is it better to use `Web Job`? or `azure function` ? or just make an `HttpRequest` ? and why is that ?

Am i already on the right way of doing this? is the `logic app` the best way that allows me to do so ?

Note: **EDIT**

files sizes are around some Mb (not very big sizes) `CSV` files with ";" as seperator
the input is `csv` file on ftp server and the output is decrypted csv file under specific "folder" on azure blob storage

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What format are the files and how big are they?

Comment: I forgot to mention that,  tiny files (some Mb) ill edit my post to add this onformation

Comment: And what format are they?

Comment: @Johns-305 csv files with ; as seperator

Comment: So, both the source and destination are CSV?  What are the formats of both?

Comment: @Johns-305 yes, the input is csv file on ftp and the output is decrypted file on azure blob storage

Comment: OK, but you say you want to do some transformation.  What is the output format?  Also CSV?  JSON? Xml?  Precisely, how are the files encrypted?  Input and output.

Comment: @Johns-305 the format will remain csv. i will rework the description in my question the way it can be more clear

Comment: @Johns-305 i hope that it's more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches and based on the answer of `evilSnobu` and the comments of `Johns-305`, i figured out that the best way to do this is like following...

note: I have an `Azure Api App` developed to do content decryption

Based on this grid, the best choice here is obviously logic apps to design my workflow:

[image: logic App vs MS Flow]

Inside my Logic App

1. Create ftp trigger : When a `files is added` on ftp -> `Create a blob` on Azure storage `&` `Delete file` from ftp
2. Create an `Azure function`

   > (Azure function vs web jobs in the below grid)

   based on `blob creation trigger`, when a blob is created call decryption api app.
3. For granularity reasons and to make azure function do only one elementary job,  i
   have to create a second Azure function to do the file parsing and
   creation of `by version-folders` depending on `version field`
   content of the file

And based on the following grid, we can tell why azure Functions fit better than web jobs in my case

[image: Azure functions vs Web jobs]

Finally, summarize this, i can say that in my case, i need to have a developer view of my solutions so that's why i needed the logic app mainly, then i have to do two elementary tasks which are **trigger based not continious** so that's better suited to `Azure Functions` and **a lot cheaper** (since files are not big and processing will be very quick)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few key factors you should take into consideration while choosing between Azure Webjobs and Azure Function.

Azure Functions have two types of billing schemes:
Consumption Plan and App Service Plan.

In consumption you pay only for a time when you function is running, however, under consumption plan, your function can't run more than 10 minutes. Which means, that if your jobs run more than 10 minutes Consumption plan is not for you.

App Service plan is the same plan used by Azure Web Jobs, you don't have time limitation here (as per documentation).

In general, Azure Functions are good when you need flexible logic with different triggers, etc.

Comment: Thenk you for your answer but it does not reply to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by logic app and function app as follows:

1. create a ftp trigger(when the file arrives)
2. If it is simple Encode Decode you can use corresponding shape or else you can create one Azure Function under consumption plan(for pricing according to the usage) which has encryption,decryption functionality where the data will be passed from FTP trigger shape.
   This requires coding you can develop it by VS Code or Visual studio.
3. Then you can do parsing from the output of Azure Function using parse or you can use transform shape for your data formats(XML, JSON etc) and you can use decrypt again using Azure function which you wrote above just different methods inside the same function.
4. Finally use the Blob shape to push the output of the Decryption to the blob storage Container.

Logic apps gives you wide usage of connectors making it easy to connect to different artefacts and a workflow approach, you can also use transformation with XSLT, liquid using integration account if needed.

Hope this helps Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but why is it better to work with azure function and not web job here? can you explain please?

Comment: Azure functions are built on the basis of webjobs, where it has more capabilities such as  Lots of languages supported, Fully managed, dynamic scaling, Easy to use portal w/ UX for managing connections , more connectors etc., It's cost effective with the consumption plan whereas in webjobs you have to pay for the app plan irrespective of usage.
In detail difference is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs

Comment: @can you provide some code sample or useful links for steps 3 and 4 that you described above please ?

Comment: @HaithemKAROUI :1) here is a sample code in C# for pgp key decrypt which you can  enhance it into an azure function.
2)Here is a sample link for xml transformation : https://integration.team/2017/07/14/working-xml-logic-apps/ with logic apps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overengineer it.

Use a Logic App to poll the FTP server and detect new files, place them in blob storage.

Create a blob-triggered Azure Function (Consumption Plan, v2 runtime) and do your data transformation in code (in v2 you have a choice between TypeScript, JavaScript, C# and Python). Write the results to blob storage with a blob output binding.

**OPTIONAL** Have a second Logic App trigger on the resulting blobs and e-mail/text you notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the (Azure Function) or (Web Job)

Here are two patterns:
-   Using Docker Containers to perform a transform (copy in this case): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-azure-block-blob-storage-backup/
-   Using a function to perform an operation after a blob created event: https://cmatskas.com/copy-azure-blob-data-between-storage-accounts-using-functions/

Please let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but one of the questions here was is it better to use web job? or azure function? and why?

Comment: whether you wanted a light weight short lived function (Azure Function) or something that could run longer with more processing (Web Job) based on that you can