# Create a logic app to include azure function and deploy using CI/CD pipeline.2e

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I have just now started to explore the logic app and have designed the given workflow:

[image]
So what happens here is: When an email arrived in my inbox, it will take the email body and pass it to the azure function where it processes the email.

I have written an azure function using visual studio 2019 and able to delpoy. I have also managed to establish CI/CD for the azure function.

But I am creating a logic app workflow in the azure portal and using the deployed function. I am wondering if this is the good approach to do? Since, the logic app uses azure function, is there any way that I can write code in VS to bundle them together and may be deploy both at once via the same CI/CD pipeline which I have been using for the azure function.

But why would I want to do that ??

- Because while testing I would like to monitor inbox of test email account. But would like to monitor my email account when it goes live.
- Similarly azure function makes an api call which would be some testapi url during dev/test and actual url when it is live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend building solutions in VS than in portal, as that will give more code flexibilty.

You can use one of the below options in VS.

1st Option: One solution which will hold Azure Function Projects as you can resue it across other Integrations. You can add more Azure function Projects to it, if it is reusable. Another solution with Azure logic apps.

2nd option You can create one Solution with Azure Function and Azure logic app Projects in the same if the function is specific to the logic app.

1.Azure Function as you have already built you can place the same and make use of CI/CD for deployment and make it avaiable for the logic app.
2.Azure Logic App in a sepearte project which will consume the Azure function, you have to parameterise Azure Function call in order to deploy it for multiple environments within the logic app.

Please note in order to consume Azure function within logic app, it has to be deployed before hand so in CI/CD you would have to deploy Azure Function first and then you can deploy Azure logic app, so that it's accessible.

3rd Option: you can have both Azure function and logic apps in the same project, but this would be ideal if you want to make use of link-template. This might also make the project unorganised over the time unless the structure is been followed.

PS: these links might help to build in VS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/manage-logic-apps-with-visual-studio
Cheers!
Suraj Revankar